# Azure service fabric with Ocelot API gateway 404 error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, ocelot

I have created Azure service fabric application with several stateless and stateful   services. All my statefull services are accessible via a Web Api stateless service.  Now I have added Ocelot API gateway to another stateless web api service and I want to access all my services from that gateway only. Now when I am trying to access the services from my API gateway service, it gives me 404.

**Ocelot configurtion**

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product/seed",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product/randomize",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "http://localhost:8314"
        }
      ],
      "QoSOptions": {
        "TimeoutValue": 360000
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:8445"
  }
}
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging locally, you don't need to add the protocol scheme and port on the host configuration man, you can omit the HTTP Traffic from the Host value and include a sibling property for the port (See example below):

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "demo.api.gateway",
      "Port": 52792
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
},
```

BTW, I've written an API gateway tutorial about API gateways and ASP.net Core + Ocelot, if you're interested to learn more about API gateways, you might want to check this article:

https://www.pogsdotnet.com/2018/08/api-gateway-in-nutshell.html

Hope it helps!
Allan

Comment: Can you please check this question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828750/re-routing-error-asp-net-core-with-ocelot-7-0-4